# ARFF to CSV multiple files conversions

Tags: weka

Anyone successfully tried to convert many ARFF files to CSV files from windows Command line.

I tried to use `weka.core.converters.CSVSaver` but it works for a single file only.

Can it be done for multiple files?

Comment: Can you show us how you did it? There's probably a way to modify your script to handle multiple files.

Comment: I used the following command:C:\Users\User\Desktop>java -cp "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\weka.jar;." weka.core.converters.CSVSaver -i ID440_Com1.arff -o ID440_Com1.csv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to solve this conversion by using R as shown in the following Script:

```
#### Set the default directory to the folder that contains all ARFF files 

temp = list.files(pattern="*.arff")
library(foreign)

for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.arff(temp[i]))

for(i in 1:length(temp))
{
mydata=read.arff(temp[i])
t=temp[i]
x=paste(t,".csv")
write.csv(mydata,x,row.names=FALSE)
mydata=0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a windows command line, type `powershell`

Change to the directory where your *.arff files reside in

Enter this command

`dir *.arff | Split-Path -Leaf|  ForEach-Object {Invoke-Expression  "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\weka.jar;." weka.core.converters.CSVSaver -i $_ -o $_.csv"}`

This assumes that your filenames do not contain any blanks, and all arff files reside in a single directory, and you want to convert them all. It will create a new csv file from each arff file. `myfile.arff` will be exported/converted  to `myfile.arff.csv`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it is not working and I got the following error:  The term 'csv2arff' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
 file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was in
cluded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:9
+ csv2arff <<<<  ID441.arff ID441.arff.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (csv2arff:String) [], CommandNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update but still not working, I jusy got ">>" after I enerd the updated command. Not sure what to do.

Comment: It was probably due to the blank in "Program Files".

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple python script in [github: arff2csv.py](https://github.com/colinwke/wktk4py/blob/master/multi_label/arff2csv.py).

paste my code.

```py
"""trans multi-label *.arff file to *.csv file."""
import re


def trans_arff2csv(file_in, file_out):
    """trans *.arff file to *.csv file."""
    columns = []
    data = []
    with open(file_in, 'r') as f:
        data_flag = 0
        for line in f:
            if line[:2] == '@a':
                # find indices
                indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(line) if x == ' ']
                columns.append(re.sub(r'^[\'\"]|[\'\"]$|\\+', '', line[indices[0] + 1:indices[-1]]))
            elif line[:2] == '@d':
                data_flag = 1
            elif data_flag == 1:
                data.append(line)

    content = ','.join(columns) + '\n' + ''.join(data)

    # save to file
    with open(file_out, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multi_label.arff2csv import trans_arff2csv

    # setting arff file path
    file_attr_in = r'D:\Downloads\birds\birds-test.arff'
    # setting output csv file path
    file_csv_out = r"D:\Downloads\birds\birds-test.csv"
    # trans
    trans_arff2csv(file_attr_in, file_csv_out)
```